# tinting the google map icon

Tags: java, android

I want to tint an icon for my google maps. Here is my code -

```
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_location));
```

How can I tint to the color I want? Currently the drawable is in green color.

Comment: when you say icon you mean the marker icon??

Comment: yes the marker icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily, you can set your image drawable which is placed in your drawable folder. This is not tint but this is best solution.

```
itmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable)

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
         .title("Current Location")
         .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
         .icon(icon);

mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

**Update**

You can use this to change color of your bitmap

```
 private Bitmap changeBitmapColor(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int color) {

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
            sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color, 1);
    p.setColorFilter(filter);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, p);
    return resultBitmap;
}
```

for using bitmap `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap`, let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: You mentioned what the questioner posted, only you declared a variable before hand.

Comment: I want to tint it, that is my question

Comment: But I dont have a image view

Comment: Dude i told you idea. No worries , i changed method for you. use it. You will not get imageview in this method. ;)